Create valid TValue<TNotifyEvent> in C++ Builder 12
I need to assign event property at runtime using RTTI. But I can't create TValue with type of
TNotifyEvent it is always void (__closure *)(class System::TObject *) __attribute__((fastcall)).
I've created helper method which could assist in set event at runtime, but continuously getting  EInvalidCast with message 'Invalid class typecast'.
void __fastcall setProperty(TObject * component, const String name, TValue value)
{
    auto * context = getContext(); // TRttiContext *
    auto * property = context->GetType(component->ClassType())->GetProperty(name);
    volatile String valueType = AnsiString(value.TypeInfo->Name); // "void (__closure *)(class System::TObject *) __attribute__((fastcall))"
    volatile String propertyType = property->PropertyType->Name; // "TNotifyEvent"
    volatile String oldType = AnsiString(property->GetValue(component).TypeInfo->Name); // "TNotifyEvent"
    property->SetValue(component, value); // Raising exception
}

Calling side:
btn is TButton *
auto value = TValue::From<TNotifyEvent>(&closeBtnClick);
setProperty(btn, "OnClick", value);

Also tried to use TMethod based on this question, but same exception raised:
context is TRttiContext *
auto * method = context->GetType(__classid(TStandardPanel))->GetMethod("closeBtnClick");
TMethod * handler = new TMethod();
handler->Code = method->CodeAddress;
handler->Data = this;
auto value = TValue::From(TNotifyEvent(handler));
setProperty(btn, "OnClick", value);

But when I assign it directly it works:
btn->OnClick = &closeBtnClick;

Also it works if get TValue from other property and reassign to current.

@RemyLebeau, I've tried, but delphi rtti doesn't know type, named TNotifyEvent. It throws Delphi style classes have to be derived from Delphi style classes compile time or if you'll try to FindClass nullptr would be result.

"delphi rtti doesn't know type, named TNotifyEvent" - yes, it does, otherwise all DFM streaming of TNotifyEvent-based events would not work. "It throws Delphi style classes have to be derived from Delphi style classes compile time or if you'll try to FindClass nullptr would be result" - that is because TNotifyEvent is not a class type, so you can't use __classid or __typeinfo() on it, and FindClass() would not know about it. But you can use TRttiContext::FindType() to find it. I have posted an answer now to show this.

TNotifyEvent is a typedef in C++:
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TNotifyEvent)(System::TObject* Sender);

A typedef is NOT a distinct type with its own RTTI.  It is just an alias.  Which is why you see the type of TNotifyEvent being reported as void (__closure *)(class System::TObject *) __attribute__((fastcall)), because that is the actual type as C++ sees it.
This is different than Delphi, where TNotifyEvent is a distinct type with its own RTTI.
Your TMethod attempt is wrong. Get rid of new, you are type-casting the TMethod* pointer wrong.  You would need something more like this instead:
TMethod handler;
handler.Code = method->CodeAddress;
handler.Data = this;
auto value = TValue::From(reinterpret_cast<TNotifyEvent&>(handler));

Or:
auto value = TValue::From(*reinterpret_cast<TNotifyEvent*>(&handler));

Or:
TNotifyEvent handler;
TMethod &m = reinterpret_cast<TMethod&>(handler);
m.Code = method->CodeAddress;
m.Data = this;
auto value = TValue::From(handler);

But, in any of those cases, you are always going to get the TValue type as void (__closure *)(class System::TObject *) __attribute__((fastcall)) since that is the real type of TNotifyEvent on the C++ side.
So, to do what you are attempting, you need the Delphi RTTI for TNotifyEvent.  You can get that from TRttiContext::FindType(), and then pass it to TValue::Make(), eg:
PTypeInfo GetTNotifyEventTypeInfo()
{
    auto * context = getContext();
    auto * type = context->FindType(_D("System.Classes.TNotifyEvent"));
    return type->Handle;
}

...

auto handler = closeBtnClick;
TValue value;
TValue::Make(&handler, GetTNotifyEventTypeInfo(), value);
setProperty(btn, _D("OnClick"), value);

However, many other event types exist than just TNotifyEvent, so this is not a very flexible approach.
A better solution is to simply query the TypeInfo from the actual property that you are assigning to, which will always have the correct RTTI (otherwise DFM streaming would not work, etc), eg:
PTypeInfo GetPropertyTypeInfo(TObject * component, const String name)
{
    auto * context = getContext();
    auto * type = context->GetType(component->ClassType());
    auto * property = type->GetProperty(name);
    return property->PropertyType->Handle;
}

...

auto handler = closeBtnClick;
TValue value;
TValue::Make(&handler, GetPropertyTypeInfo(btn, _D("OnClick")), value);
setProperty(btn, _D("OnClick"), value);


Why should I not to use new in current case? Somewhere I've read that any TObject based instances should be created only by using new.

@ИнгибиторПалладиум Yes, all TObject-derived types must be created with new in C++, but TMethod is not a TObject-derived type, it is not even a class, it is a struct. It is a value type, so it can (and should) be created on the stack rather than the heap.  Also, using new requires delete to avoid a memory leak. And, the way you were type-casting a TMethod* pointer (whatever way you obtained it) into a TNotifyEvent was incorrect syntax anyway.

Sorry for type casting. I'm think that it would be construct in place. And thanks for your detail explanation.
